# Prove or disprove $x_n$ converge to $x$ if and only if $x_{2k}$ converge to $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or disprove that $x_n$ converges to $x$ if and only if $x_{2k}$ converges to $x$

I think it is provable that if any sequence converges to $x$ then any subsequence of it must converge to $x$

But does it hold true in the opposite direction?

Comment: What about the sequence that's $1$ in even places and $0$ in odd?

Comment: Information about $x_{2k}$ doesn't tell anything at all about $x_{2k+1}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Look at $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ defined by $$x_n=(-1)^n.$$

Comment: Beat me (because of character count requirements) :)

Comment: Ok but is it provable if we say xn converge to x iff x2k converge to x and x(2k+1) converge to x ??

Comment: Of course ! Do it ! ;-)